# Save checked value Checkbox array POST

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes and save the checked values in an array. However, when someone clicks 'submit' and they get an error, all their checked boxes are forgotten. Usually I would let the script remember the checked boxes with a code like

IF checkbox value = OK { echo checked="checked"}

However, now I save it in an array and I have no idea how to do this?

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT merknaam FROM merken";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"merken[]\" value='" . $row['merknaam'] . "'>&nbsp;" . $row['merknaam'] . " <Br />  ";
}

?>
```

This is the code I use for the checkboxes. Next I display the array with this code:

```
$merkenstring = implode(",", $_POST['merken']);

echo $merkenstring;
```

Result: AC Ryan,Adidas,Agu,Cargo

I hope someone could give me a code example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are posting this to the same page, and `$_POST['merken']` is still available after an error, use `in_array()` to test each checkbox's value against the current set in `$_POST`:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // If the current value is in the $_POST['merken'] array
    // and the array has been initialized...
    if (isset($_POST['merken']) && is_array($_POST['merken']) && in_array($row['merknaam'], $_POST['merken'])) {
      // Set the $checked string
      $checked = "checked='checked'";
    }
    // Otherwise $checked is an empty string
    else $checked = "";
    // And incorporate it into your <input> tag
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;<input $checked type=\"checkbox\" name=\"merken[]\" value='" . $row['merknaam'] . "'>&nbsp;" . $row['merknaam'] . " <Br />  ";
    //----------------------^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

If this was posted to a different script, you would (as with any post value returned to a previous script) need to store the array in `$_SESSION` instead and compare against `$_SESSION['merken']` in your `in_array()` call.

Comment: You Sir are my saviour! Working like a charm after incorporating the variable inside the echo in the right way. Little problem though, at first, when there is no string just yet, I get this error message before very result from the table: 

Warning: in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument in /vhosts/thecompanytree.nl/httpdocs/signup.php on line 487

How do I fix this?

Comment: @user1555076 See change above.  Test with isset(), is_array() to be sure $_POST['merken'] exists.

Comment: Not sure I completely understand, but I'm gonnna work on that. It works like a charm!

Comment: @user1555076 Important to understand... The first time your page loads, `$_POST` is empty, and by extension `$_POST['merken']` is not set.  So we test if that post key is already set, and if it _is_ set, that it is also an array.  Then we know it is safe to use in `in_array()`.  If it was not yet set, then it just proceeds to the `else` case and makes `$checked` an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$row['merknaam']` is the checkbox value, and `$_POST['merken']` holds an array of checked checkbox values, then you simply need to check if the value is in the array:

```
if (in_array($row['merknaam'], $_POST['merken'])) {
   // this checkbox should be checked
}
```